# Windows 10 Universal App Feedback

Tags: c#, windows-10, feedback

How in Windows 10 Unviersal Application invoke Feedback Page in Store?
In Windows Phone 8.1 i used

```
 await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
         new Uri(@"ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId));
```

but now it's not worked for me

Comment: Is your Windows 10 app published yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reference an `appid` in the link use the PackageFamilyName

```
ms-windows-store://review/?PFN=xxxx
```

where `xxxx` comes from `Windows.ApplicationModel.PackageId.FamilyName`